# Caesar cipher outputs blank line

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

I am doing a problem set from the CS50 course and we have to implement Caesar's cipher. The following code works only with numbers (they remain the same as intended), when you put in a character, however, nothing is output. What's wrong?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
//problem set requires arguments
int main (int argc, string argv [])
{
    int i = 0;

    if (argc != 2){
        printf ("Retry\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        int x = atoi(argv [1]);
        //gets plaintext
        string a = get_string ("plaintext:");
        printf("ciphertext:");
        for (i = 0; i <= strlen(a); i++){
            //if character is a number it remains unchanged
            if (isdigit(a[i])){
                printf ("%c", a[i]);
            } else {
                if (isupper(a[i])){
                    //converts from ASCII index to alphabetical index
                    char y = a[i] - 65;
                    //Caesar cipher formula. If upper case remains upper case.
                    y = toupper(a[i] + x % 26);
                    //goes back ASCII
                    printf("%c", y + 65);
                    } else if (islower(a[i])){
                    //converts from ASCII index to alphabetical index
                    char t = a[i] - 65;
                    //Caesar cipher formula. If lower case remains lower case.
                    t = tolower(a[i] + x % 26);
                    //goes back to ASCII
                    printf("%c", t + 65);
                    }
                }
           }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why `y = toupper(..`? It already is an uppercase letter per the above `if`, and it's (at the same time) *not* any letter because you already subtracted 65 from it.

Comment: Without looking it up: I would think that I'd rather use some parentheses to make `a = b + c % d` do *exactly* what I mean, rather than relying on precedence. It also makes it easier to guess what you do for someone else who reads your code.

Comment: Where is `get_string()` defined? According to the version I have, it's NOT defined in `cs50.h`.

Comment: There are over 300 questions tagged [tag:caesar-cipher], many of them also tagged [tag:cs50].  Have you looked among them for answers to your problems?  Your code is hard to read. The indentation and bracing of the second `else if` doesn't match the first.  I'm not clear how you handle non-alphanumeric characters (AFAICT, you skip them completely).

Comment: @MarkBenningfield: There was a major revision to the `cs50.h` and `cs50.c` code a year or two (or three?) ago, and names like `get_string()` were added then (supplanting the older `GetString()`).  The new code does some interesting things, like managing the release (freeing) of returned strings.  It is no longer a library of code that the students of CS50 could be expected to write — whereas the old version was more or less one which they could have written at the end of the course.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yeah, that figures. That's about how old my version is (3.0).

Comment: @AdamGrey: Are you sure this is the code that doesn't work? After updating my version of cs50.h, I cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I just checked again and yes, this code doesn't work. How can I update a library? Did you have my problem before updating?

Comment: @AdamGrey: No, I didn't. By the simple expedient of swapping out the `get_string()` function with separate calls to the older (now deprecated) `GetString()` function and `printf()`, the code worked fine. Are you certain your environment can print the resulting characters? (They are in the extended range of the ASCII character set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`65` is the ASCII value for letter `'A'`. If you are working on lower case word, you would need `97`, which is ASCII value for `'a'`

You have calculated `t`, but you didn't carry the result to the next line. Moreover, you have to take the modulus on the whole line. You are expecting that `t` is between `0` and `26`, then you add it to `97`

```
char t = a[i] - 97;
t = (t + x) % 26;
printf("%c", t + 97);
```

Also the for loop should go up to `strlen(a)`. The last index in the string `a` is null-character, it should not be modified. You can also use `'a'` instead of `97` here.

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++)
{
    if(isupper(a[i]))   
    {
        char y = a[i] - 'A';
        y = (y + x ) % 26;
        printf("%c", y + 'A');
    }
    else if(islower(a[i])) 
    {
        char t = a[i] - 'a';
        t = (t + x )% 26;
        printf("%c", t + 'a');
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("%c", a[i]);
    }
}
```